# Laravel 5.4 search relationship with pivot in blade

Tags: php, laravel, search, pivot-table

I'm building a search function, but I'm having issues with one seemingly simple, but clearly difficult function.

In the search results, I have successfully displayed all the users that have a given skill. (In this case, it's a `belongsToMany()`relationship), as well as their `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email`.  I want the last part of the entry to display the user's competency (referred to as `skill_level` in the code) in the skill in question. At the moment, `skill_level` is a pivot in the skill/user relationship; they are denoted by one of four strings: "Wants to Learn", "Novice", "Intermediate", "Expert", and each has an `id` of 1-4 (inclusive).

Here's the relevant code:

Controller (partial)

```
    public function results(Request $request){

    $theskillName = $request->input('theskillName');
    $users = User::whereHas('skills', function ($q) use($theskillName) {
        $q->where('name', '=', $theskillName);
    })->get();
    $skills = Skill::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
    if(count($users) > 0){
        return view('search.search', compact('users', 'skills', 'theskillName'));
    }
    else { 
        return view ('search.search', compact('skills'));
    }
  }
```

search.blade.php (partial)

```
@if(isset($users))
<p>The following people have {{ $theskillName }} as one of their skills:</p>
<h2>People</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Skill Level</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->???->skill_level }}</td> /* <- What replaces ??? here? */
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
@endif
```

User.php (partial)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'middle', 'email', 'status', 'role', 'password'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'remember_token'
];

// Gets all of the skills the user knows
public function skills()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Skill')->withPivot('skill_level');
}
```

Everything I've tried so far either returns `null` for that final part of the entry or spits out the error `Trying to get property of non-object`. Can anyone provide some insight into what to do here?

**Update:** I tried the obvious answer `$user->pivot->skill_level`, which gave me `Trying to get property of non-object.`

Comment: when you search, add pivot_column_name

Comment: so i think in your case it would be pivot_skill_level

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A colleague gave this as the answer:

`<td>{{ $user->skills->first(function($skill) use($theskillName) { return $skill->name === $theskillName;})->pivot->skill_level}}</td>`

Not sure how secure this is, though.

Answer (score 1):

A user has many skills. So you have many skill level. You can access it like so.

```
@foreach($user->skills as $skill)
    {{ $skill->pivot->skill_level }}
@endforeach
```

or

```
{{ $user->skills()->first()->pivot->skill_level }}
```

**Edit** : Based on the comments you can do this to fetch the queried level of the queried skill.

```
{{ $user->skills()->where('skills.name', $theskillName)->first()->pivot->skill_level }}
```

Comment: First answer doesn't work because I'm searching for the USER with the queried skill. I need to have `@foreach ($users as user)` or else it won't work right.
 
My colleague (who provided me with the answer I posted) said that your second answer doesn't work because it will only grab the user's first skill, not the one being queried.

Comment: Both the answers will work. The first one will fetch all the set skill levels. The $user model is inside the loop of $users, so there's no problem. Second one was an example of how you could fetch directly. You never mentioned in your question you wanted to display only the queried skill level.